# Story where lack of scar leads to discovering impostor childhood friend

Tags: story-identification

I vaguely remember a story of a man who gets visited by someone he believes to be an old childhood friend. He hadn't seen his friend for a while, so he first ignores the feeling that something is off with his guest's stories (if I remember correctly), but then discovers that the person he's taking to is just pretending to be his childhood friend. He discovers this because he notices that a very small scar (below the eye?) from a wound he himself caused his friend back in the childhood days is not there.

The impostor is from a (secret?) government agency. I believe the man openly confronts the impostor about this, and does not get in a dangerous situation because of this. Rather, they talk about the life of the person the impostor tried to play.

The man lives far from the city, in the woods or mountains if I recall correctly. They talk for some hours, the whole story segment takes place on the deck of the house.

This might have been a short story or part of a book, I don't remember. It is at least 8 years old, bit most likely older.

Comment: Welcome to SFF:SE. You might want to have a look at our [guide](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info) to story id questions for ideas on more details to include. This may help someone think of the answer.

Comment: Do you remember what the story is **about**? What are the two men talking about? What are the fantastic or science-fictional aspects of the story? Aliens? Ghosts? Monsters? Inventions? Demons? Time travel?

Comment: "Hey, the scar is missing! That means either (A) a total stranger somehow transformed himself into a 99,9% perfect replica of my childhood friend, except for the small scar; or else (B) my childhood friend somehow got rid of the scar. Must be (A)." Could you explain the reasoning a little more?